# Find records from database with spring JDBC using where clause

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-jdbc

I want to search records for two dates from the database with spring JDBC. I used where startDate=? and endDate=? I need to correct the controller. I am getting exception as

org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver resolveException WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
[image][1]

```
    public class EmpDao {  
JdbcTemplate template;  
  
public void setTemplate(JdbcTemplate template) {  
    this.template = template;  
}  

public List<Event> getEmployees(Date start, Date end){  
    return template.query("select * from Event where startDate=? and endDate=?",new RowMapper<Event>(){  
        public Event mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {  
            Event e=new Event();  
            e.setEventName(rs.getString(1));  
            e.setEventOrgName(rs.getString(2));  
            e.setEventFare(rs.getInt(3));  
            e.setStartDate(rs.getDate(4));
            e.setEndDate(rs.getDate(5));
            return e;  
        }  
    });  
}  
}    



public class Event {  
private String eventName;  
private String eventOrgName;  
private int eventFare;  
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;

} 



@Controller  
public class EmpController {  
    @Autowired  
    EmpDao dao;
   
   @GetMapping("/viewemp")  
public String viewemp(@RequestParam(value="start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") Date start,
        @RequestParam(value="end") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") Date end, Model m){  
    List<Event> list=dao.getEmployees(start,end);  
    
    m.addAttribute("list",list);
    return "viewemp";  
}  
    
}





<h1>Add New Employee</h1>
       <form method="get" action="viewemp">  
       <input type="date" id="start" name="start"/>
        <input type="date" id="end" name="end"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        
        </form>
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have updated. can you please check

Comment: You should probably provide more context, possibly provide more code, explain what you've tried, what happened, what you expect to happen, etc.  'What's wrong with this code? Will someone fix it' questions don't get much attention.

Comment: check again pls

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: DAO not working